# Apache Mailer throwing compiler errors in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons

Created a simple Apache Commons Email object and went to compile it. Imported: `import org.apache.commons.mail._` and `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` and also did the following:

```
  def sendVerification(user: User) = {
    val email = new SimpleEmail()
        email.setHostName("smtp.sendgrid.net")
        email.setSmtpPort(465)
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("user", "pass"))
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true)
        email.setFrom("Community Admin <admin@domain.com>")
        email.setSubject("TestMail")
        email.setMsg("""Welcome %s!

        Thanks for signing up. This email is to confirm your email address.

        Cheers,
        Admin Team
        """ format user.firstName)
        email.addTo(user.email)
        email.send()
  }
```

Errors are as following:

```
[error] C:\Users\path\to\AccountService\models\User.scala:43: object mail is not a member of package javax
[error] import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
[error]              ^
[error] error while loading Email, Missing dependency 'class javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage', required by C:\Users\path\lib\commons-email-1.2.jar(org/apache/commons/mail/Email.class)
[error] C:\Users\path\com\threetierlogic\AccountService\models\User.scala:256: value setHostName is not a member of org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail
[error]                 email.setHostName("smtp.sendgrid.net")
```

However, when I go to compile it throws errors on every single method called on `val email`. Is this an issue related to mutability? Or has something changed in version `1.3`?

Comment: Fix your classpath.  It isn't finding the imported java class.

Comment: Are you referring to `javax`? Is that not part of standard Java 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mel Nicholson was pointing towards the right issue, it is related to a dependency not being fetched. I didn't realize that it didn't come with the Apache JAR I downloaded. So instead I simply added it to my sbt `Build.scala` and voila! It compiled.

`val commonsMail       = "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3"`